# Google map API not listed in Google Play services? If it does not exist what can I do instead of it?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I am new to android development and I watched a tutorial for google maps and they add the google play service api for maps: com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0, but now I cannot find it in https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup. If it does not exist then what can I do instead of it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'`

Comment: This is not my answer @Jaymin . My question is where I find 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0' ?